# node/sails js download image from web and upload to sails API

Tags: node.js, sails.js, skipper

I am trying to write an import script in Nodejs that pulls data from the web and formats it and then sends it to my API.

Part of that includes pulling artist data from LastFM, fetching the images for each artist and sending them off to my API to resize and save.

The import script is just ran in terminal.

The part of the import script that is responsible for pulling the images down and sending off to my API looks like:

```
_.forEach(artist.images, function(image){

   console.log('uploading image to server ' + image.url)
   request.get(image.url)
          .pipe(request.post('http://MyAPI/files/upload', function(err, files){
                              if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                              }
                              console.log('back from upload');
                              console.log(files);
                            }));
});
```

And the files.upload action looks like:

```
upload: function(req, res){

    console.log('saving image upload');
    console.log(req.file('image'));

    res.setTimeout(0);

    var sizes = [
        ['avatar', '280x210'],
        ['medium', '640x640'],
        ['large', '1024x768'],
        ['square', '100x100'],
        ['smallsquare', '50x50'],
        ['avatarsquare', '32x32']
    ];

    //resize to the set dimensions

    //for each dimension - save the output to gridfs

    _.forEach(sizes, function(bucket){

        var width = bucket[1, 0], height = bucket[1, 2];

        // Let's create a custom receiver
        var receiver = new Writable({objectMode: true});

        receiver._write = function(file, enc, cb) {

        gm(file).resize(width, height).upload({
            adapter: require('skipper-gridfs'),
            uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/sonatribe.' + bucket[0]
        }, function (err, uploadedFiles) {
            if (err){
                return res.serverError(err);
            }
           else{
               return res.json({
                   files: uploadedFiles,
                   textParams: req.params.all()
               });
           }
       });

       cb();
    };



    /*  req.file('image').upload(receiver, function(err, files){
    if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log('returning files');
        return files;
    });*/

   });

}
```

However, `console.log(req.file('image'));` is not what I'd hope - probably because this code is expecting the image to be uploaded as part of a multi-part form upload with a field named `image` - which it is not...

I'm trying to figure out how the file will end up inside my action but my google foo is completely out of action today and I'm fairly (very) new to Node.

Anyone able to offer some pointers?

Comment: Have you looked at [forms documentation for request](https://github.com/request/request#forms)?

Comment: Nice one - I guess this is specifically what I am looking for? https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads

Comment: I think so, you'd just need to handle passing the image to the form via a function in the pipe, and not pass it directly.

Comment: Sorry to hog you on this one, how would I handle passing the image? Would I need to turn it from a stream to an actual image?